# Add border/outline to a transparent (png) image with ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, border, transparent

I try to add border to a transparent png image, and [I found some solutions](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=16399).

But my problem is I can't increase the image size in the same amount like the border size.

Currently I use this code:

```
convert stone.png -bordercolor none -border 15 /
-background red -alpha background -channel A -blur 15x15 -level 0,0% result.png
```

First I create a transparent border to increase the image size, and it's works fine. But when I try to add the visible border with the `blur` command, I can't figure out, what parameter I should use, to set a border, what will have the size like my "transparent border".

original image:

[image: original image]

my result with the code above:

[image: my result of the image]

As you can see, the bottom corners are cutted. They should be rounded.

Comment: I do not understand what exactly your problem is. Is it that the "corners" of your red border are sort of "cut off"?

Comment: Yes, there is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If I may suggest a different approach that yields good results (you can play with the parameters for less blurring and thickness):

```
convert test.png -bordercolor none -border 10x10 -background red -alpha background -channel A -blur 0x10 -level 0,70% red_test.png
```

Hope it helps,

yakobom

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by passing a nonzero value to the first argument of `-blur`. This causes the "area" that the operator looks at to be overly constrained. Instead, pass `-blur 0x15`:

```
convert stone.png -bordercolor none -border 45 \
-background red -alpha background -channel A -blur 0x15 -level 0,0% result.png
```

Note that the value `15` is the blur sigma; the actual "area of effect" of the blur is theoretically infinite. You need to adjust your `-border` to make it fit; 3 times sigma, as I did here, is usually enough.